# How can I apply an expectations for all the columns in table in DLT

Tags: python, parallel-processing, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

I have seen tutorials, and articles everywhere it is given about using the DLT data quality expectations on the few columns from the table. Below is the code :

```
@dlt.table(
  comment="Wikipedia clickstream data cleaned and prepared for analysis."
)
@dlt.expect("valid_current_page_title", "current_page_title IS NOT NULL")
@dlt.expect_or_fail("valid_count", "click_count > 0")
def clickstream_prepared():
  return (
    dlt.read("clickstream_raw")
      .withColumn("click_count", expr("CAST(n AS INT)"))
      .withColumnRenamed("curr_title", "current_page_title")
      .withColumnRenamed("prev_title", "previous_page_title")
      .select("current_page_title", "click_count", "previous_page_title")
  )
```

here, while specifying the expectations we have to manually mention the columns on which it will be implemented. But I want them to run for all the columns in the data frame.

To implement the expectations on all the columns in the data frame I used a loop and dynamically changed the function name (which acts as a table name). But it is highly inefficient.

```
for column in columns_list_order_table:     
    exec(f'''
@dlt.table(comment="null value validations for {column}")
@dlt.expect_or_drop("null values","is_null == false")
def null_validation_orders_for_column_{column}():
    df = dlt.read("bronze_orders")
    return df.withColumn("is_null", col("{column}").isNull())
''')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`@expect_all_or_fail(expectations)`**](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/python-ref.html#python-delta-live-tables-properties)

> Declare one or more data quality constraints. `expectations` is a Python dictionary, where the key is the expectation description, and the value is the expectation constraint. If a row violates any of the expectations, immediately stop execution.

Create exceptions for all of your columns as shown below.

```py
expectations = {}
for i in columns_list:
    expectations["valid_" + i] = f"{i} IS NOT NULL"
expectations
```

Output:

```json
{'valid_state': 'state IS NOT NULL', 
'valid_store_id': 'store_id IS NOT NULL',
'valid_product_category': 'product_category IS NOT NULL', 
'valid_SKU': 'SKU IS NOT NULL',
'valid_price': 'price IS NOT NULL'}
```

Then, add this to your code as shown below.

```py
columns_list = ['state', 'store_id', 'product_category', 'SKU', 'price']

expectations = {}
for i in columns_list:
    expectations["valid_" + i] = f"{i} IS NOT NULL"
expectations

@dlt.table()
@dlt.expect_all_or_fail(expectations)
def clickstream_raw():
  return (spark.read.schema(schema).option("header", "true").format("csv").load("/path/csv/"))
```

If any one column contains null, it will raise an exception violation error. If you are using CSV data, set the `header` option to `true` because it will raise an error if you don't provide it, as column names will be included in the record.

Comment: How can I do the same for custom expectations that are not inbuilt? Such as checking if the dates in the date columns are valid or not. Such expectations require column-level transformations. And how can then I quarantine them ie. separating the invalid ones. Any high level implementation idea?

Comment: You have to use `except_all` passing the dictionary giving the constraints in key value pairs as how I given in the post.

Comment: Refer the documentation given the post.